# Spring API return a file rather than String

Tags: java, spring, endpoint

I have the code below as an api endpoint. I want the json string to be displayed on browser when I access the endpoint.

However, when I access the endpoint, a file is downloaded. The file named api.json contains `{"key": "myKey"}`. I have no idea why it generates a file. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

```
@GetMapping(path="/getFields2", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity getFieldssec(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
{
    return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"key\": \"myKey\"}");
}
```

Comment: The server just sends the JSON. The browser then decides what to do and it decided to download it

Comment: use header `Content-Disposition=inline`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Spring Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) and return it

```
@GetMapping(path="/getFields2", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public  ResponseEntity<Resource> getFieldssec(
        @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    String text="{\"key\": \"myKey\"}";
    Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(text.getBytes());

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentLength(text.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(resource);
}
```